# How old are Kylo Ren and Rey?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

The actor for Kylo is in his early thirties, so I assumed his character is as well (which would also fit with the age of his parents), but I keep seeing people refer to him as a moody teenager (which may not be referring to age, but rather his manner). As for Rey, I assumed she was late teens/early twenties, but this is only backed up by how she behaves and her personality, not necessarily any facts.

Honestly I just want him to be old enough to support my theory that he

> murdered younglings in front of a youngling Rey Skywalker!!!

Comment: It's highly unlikely that either of them are over 30; TFA is supposedly set ~30 years after RotJ.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### **Rey**:

*TFA Visual Dictionary* says "**19-year-old Rey**"

### **Kylo Ren**:

There is ***no canon answer as of right now***.

However, Pablo Hidalgo [answered Kylo Ren's age on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/678330999772610560):

> Kylo Ren's BFF ‏@jimwade Dec 19
>
> Hey @pablohidalgo do we have any idea what Kylo's age is in TFA? Around 30?
>
> Pablo Hidalgo @pablohidalgo @jimwade around there. **29-30**.

Please be aware that Hidalgo's Twitter account explicitly says "*Don't cite tweets as canon*" - which Wookieepedia promptly ignored :)

Comment: I just realized, does this mean there's a nonzero chance that Kylo's father is actually Wicket?

Answer (score 18):

*The Force Awakens* takes place 30 years after the end of *The Return of the Jedi*.

Unfortunately, no real clues are provided regarding Rey's age.

Ben, however is 29 years old at the time of *The Force Awakens*.

In [*Aftermath: Empires's End*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Empire%27s_End) Leia gives birth to Ben shortly following the end of The Battle of Jakku, which takes place in 5ABY (and 1 year after the Battle of Endor)

Comment: Lol, Kylo's a "celebration" baby!

Answer (score 3):

The movie takes place 30 years after the battle of Endor. Rey was born 11 years after Endor making her 19 years old. However, Ben, or Kylo Ren was born 0-1 years after Endor making him either 29 or 30.

[Sources of information: The book: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary has details about Rey's age, 19, while I found Kylo Ren's age while researching through Wookieepedia (as unreliable as that sounds it fits with the appearance of the actor and timeline of the movie, in relation to when Han and Leia met... etc...)]

Comment: What is your source for this information?

Comment: Re to Dave Johnson about the source of information: The book: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary has details about Rey's age, 19, while I found Kylo Ren's age while reseaching through Wookieepedia (as unreliable as that sounds it fits with the appearence of the actor and timeline of the movie, in relation to when Han and Leia met... etc...)

Comment: @ Dave Johnson - starwars.wikia.com

Comment: So basically a 6 or 7 year old Rey (currently a Padawan of Luke), was hidden away on Jakku because a 17/18 year old Kylo Ren was going through a teenage strop and decided to take it out on all the other Padawans.