# How long has Rey been on Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, rey

I've been wondering about basic information about Rey, including **how long she's been on Jakku.**

I was thinking that this might also give us her age because she looked to be about four when her parents left her.

Comment: Rey's age is already known - ["How old are Kylo Ren and Rey?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111560/how-old-are-kylo-ren-and-rey)

Answer (score 6):

### She's been on Jakku for 13 years alone (in Plutt's care), and also spent several years with her parents on Jakku.

The latest (canon) star wars novel places her with her parents at ***six* years of age**, shortly before they left her on Jakku.

> The man [Rey's father] craned his neck around as he watched his wife wrestle with the
> controls, then he stood and **leaned down to kiss the head of the
> six-year-old girl strapped securely in the seat**, a large pair of
> navigator’s sound-deadening headphones over her ears. In front of the
> girl, the an­cient navigation panel—a square matrix of hundreds of
> individual tiny square lights—flashed in multicolored patterns of
> moving shapes, a simple game the girl’s mother had loaded into the
> auxiliary computer to keep her daughter occupied on the long journey.
>
> <sub><sup>['Star Wars: Shadow of the Sith' exclusive excerpt: Rey's parents showcased in Luke Skywalker-centric story](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/books/2022/05/19/star-wars-shadow-sith-exclusive-excerpt-reys-parents-luke-skywalker/9820101002/)</sup></sub>

Her age at the time The Force Awakens takes place has been confirmed (in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111564/20774)) to be **19 years of age.**

### <s>At present we don't know.</s>

<s>Rey's earliest history isn't described in any great detail in any of the canon novels or factbooks. We do know that after "several years" (and by the age of ten) she'd managed to scrounge her own shelter and we know that the actress that played young Rey [Cailey Fleming](https://dorksideoftheforce.com/2016/01/18/meet-the-actress-who-played-young-rey-in-star-wars-the-force-awakens/) was 6.5 years of age when she filmed the role. We have an unconfirmed article in [Variety](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/star-wars-force-awakens-rey-daisy-ridley-episode-8-rogue-one-felicity-jones-1201664087/) that places her age at ***five*** when she was abandoned but obviously none of this is sufficiently canon that it can't be subject to change.</s>

> <s>***We first meet Rey on the desert planet of Jakku, where she was
> abandoned by her parents at five years old,** and it doesn’t take long
> before she’s swept up on an equally momentous quest alongside John
> Boyega’s Finn and the scene-stealing new droid BB-8. Variety spoke to
> Ridley about the surreal experience of joining the “Star Wars”
> universe, watching director J.J. Abrams turn into a “fanboy” around
> Harrison Ford, and her own star-struck moment meeting “Star Wars:
> Rogue One” lead Felicity Jones.*</s>

---

Answer (score 0):

According to the data given in Valorum's answer, Rey would have been on Jakku about 14 years if she was 5 years old when abandoned and about 12 or 13 yeas if she was the same age when abandoned as the actress portraying young Rey.

As Valorum says there is no certainty about Rey's age when abandoned and new canonical stories might be published at any time to give her a different canonical age when abandoned.  Since an older child would have a better chance of survival when abandoned, the writers of hypothetical canonical stories stating Rey's age when abandoned might want to make her time alone on Jakku closer to 10 year than to 15 years.

But who knows if those writers of hypothetical future stories will consider matters of plausibility.

Comment: she wasn't abandoned alone in the desert - we see / hear her being held by Unkar Plutt in TFA flashback. 5 yr old is reasonable in that situation

Comment: You actually see her being handed over in the film and there's a wealth of info in the "Rey's Diary" factbook about her unpleasant childhood with Plutt.